# Handling windows events in a tight loop?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, cpu-usage

I have written a compiler and interpreter for a scripting language.   The interpreter is a DLL ('The Engine') which runs in a single thread and can load many 100s or 1000s of compiled byte-code applications and excecute them as a set of internal processes.     There is a main loop that excecutes a few instructions from each of the loaded app processes before moving one to the next process.

The byte code instruction in the compiled apps can either be a low level instructions (pop, push, add, sub etc) or a call to an external function library (which is where most of the work is done).     These external libararies can call back to the engine to put the internal processes into a sleep state waiting for a particular event upon which the external function (probably after receiving an event) will wake up the internal process again.         If all internal processes are in a sleep state (which the are most of the time) then I can put the Engine to sleep as well thus handing off the CPU to other threads.

However there is nothing to prevent someone writing a script which just does a tight loop like this:

while(1) 
   x=1;
endwhile

Which means my main loop will never enter a sleep state and so the CPU goes up to 100% and locks up the system.     I want my engine to run as fast as possibly, whilst still handling windows events so that other applications are still responsive when a tight loop similar to the above is encountered.

So my first question is how to add code to my main loop to ensure windows events are handled without slowing down the main engine which should run at the fastest speed possible..

Also it would be nice to be able to set the maximum CPU usage my engine can use and throttle down the CPU usage by calling the occasional Sleep(1)..

So my second question is how can I throttle down then CPU usage to the required level?

The engine is written in Borland C++ and makes calls to the win32 API.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're making a cooperative multitasking scheme, and a script doesn't cooperate - should you really force it? Make a preemptive mechanism if that's what you want.

Comment: IMHO you're going a step backward (ala windows 3.1).  You have a full multi-process and multi-thread capable operating system.  Why not just let each script run in it's own thread and manage that threads.  The operating system will be responsible to perform the context switches and assign processor time for each of the scripts.  You can then control thread priorities and manage thread lifetime.  For infinite loops as the shown you can take some steps on your engine to terminate the problematic threads and even if you don't, this will never stops other scripts from running.

Comment: Sean, you seem to be new to SO: welcome :)  It's been a few days since the last answer was posted.  You should upvote answers you find useful (click the triangle above the number on the top left of an answer) and if any answer your question well, mark it as the accepted answer (click the tick.)  We go to a lot of effort to answer questions here, and it's altruistic, but it's nice to get the 'reward' of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Running a message loop at the same time as running your script

> I want my engine to run as fast as
>   possibly, whilst still handling
>   windows events so that other
>   applications are still responsive when
>   a tight loop similar to the above is
>   encountered.

The best way to continue running a message loop while performing another operation is to move that other operation to another thread.  In other words, move your script interpreter to a second thread and communicate with it from your main UI thread, which runs the message loop.

When you say Borland C++, I assume you're using C++ Builder?  In this situation, the main thread is the only one that interacts with the UI, and its message loop is run via [`Application->Run`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_Run.html).  If you're periodically calling [`Application->ProcessMessages`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_ProcessMessages.html) in your library callbacks, that's reentrant and can cause problems.  Don't do it.

One comment to your question suggested moving each script instance to a separate thread.  This would be ideal.  However, beware of issues with the DLLs the scripts call if they keep state - DLLs are loaded per-process, not per-thread, so if they keep state you may encounter threading issues.  For the moment purely to address your current question, I'd suggest moving all your script execution to a single other thread.

You can communicate between threads many ways, such as by posting messages between them using [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Since you're using Borland C++, you should have access to the VCL.  It has a good thread wrapper class called [TThread](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TThread.html).  Derive from this and put your script loop in Execute.  You can use [Synchronize](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!OVERLOADED_Synchronize_Classes_TThread.html) (blocks waiting) or [Queue](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!OVERLOADED_Queue_Classes_TThread.html) (doesn't block; method may be run at any time, when the target thread processes its message loop) to run methods in the context of another thread.

As a side note:

> so that other
>   applications are still responsive when
>   a tight loop similar to the above is
>   encountered.

This is odd.  In a modern, preemptively multitasked version of Windows other applications should still be responsive even when your program is very busy.  Are you doing anything odd with your thread priorities, or are you using a lot of memory so that other applications are paged out?

### 2. Handling an infinite loop in a script

You write:

> there is nothing to prevent someone
>   writing a script which just does a
>   tight loop like this:
>
> while(1) x=1; endwhile
>
> Which means my main loop will never
>   enter a sleep state and so the CPU
>   goes up to 100% and locks up the
>   system.

but phrase how to handle this as:

> Also it would be nice to be able to
>   set the maximum CPU usage my engine
>   can use and throttle down the CPU
>   usage by calling the occasional
>   Sleep(1)..
>
> So my second question is how can I
>   throttle down then CPU usage to the
>   required level?

I think you're taking the wrong approach.  An infinite loop like `while(1) x=1; endwhile` is a bug in the script, but it should not take down your host application.  Just throttling the CPU won't make your application able to handle the situation.  (And using lots of CPU isn't necessarily a problem: if it the work is available for the CPU to run, do it!  *There's nothing holy about using only a bit of your computer's CPU*.  It's there to use after all.)  What (I think) you really want is to be able to continue to have your application able to respond when running this script (solved by a second thread) and then:

1. Detect when a script is 'not responding', or not calling into your callbacks
2. Be able to take action, such as asking the user if they want to terminate the script

An example of another program that does this is Firefox.  If you go to a page with a misbehaving script, eventually you'll get a dialog asking if you want to stop the script running.

Without knowing more about how your script is actually interpreted or run, I can't give a detailed answer to these two.  But I can suggest an approach, which is:

1. Your interpreter probably runs a loop, getting the next instruction and executing it.  Your interactivity is currently provided by a callback running from one of those instructions being executed.  I'd suggest making use of that by having your callback simply log the time it was last called.  Then in your processing thread, every instruction (or every ten or a hundred) check the current time against the last callback time.  If a long time has passed, say fifteen or thirty seconds, it may be an indication that the script is stuck.  Notify the main thread but keep processing.

   For "time", something like [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is probably sufficient.
2. Next step: Your main UI thread can react to this by asking the user what to do.  If they want to terminate the script, communicate with the script thread to set a flag.  In your script processing loop, again every instruction (or hundred) check for this flag, and if it's set, stop.

   When you move to having one thread per script interpreter, you `TThread`'s `Terminated` flag for this.  Idiomatically for something that runs infinitely in a thread, you run in a `while (!Terminated && [any other conditions])` loop in your `Execute` function.

To actually answer your question about using less CPU, the best approach is probably to change your thread's priority using [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to a lower priority, such as `THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL`.  It will still run if nothing else needs to run.  This will affect your script's performance.  Another approach is to use [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as you suggest, but this really is artificial.  Perhaps [SwitchToThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is slightly better - it yields to another thread the OS chooses.  Personally, I think the CPU is there to use, and if you solve the problem of an interactive UI and handling out-of-control scripts then there should be no problem with using all CPU if your script needs it.  If you're using "too much" CPU, perhaps the interpreter itself could be optimised.  You'll need to run a profiler and find out where the CPU time is being spent.

Comment: Thanks for that comprehensive response.. My interpreter DLL is run in it's own thread, but it will lock up the GUI front end and slow down the whole machine if this thread enters a tight loop.  I think the answer is to call ProcessMessages via Synchronise to ensure windows events are still processed.            There are a number of reasons why I didn't run scripts in separate threads,  one of them being that there might be many 1000's of scripts running simulataneously and I was not keen on the idea of 5000 OS threads being created...

Comment: You could create a few and have each thread run several script instances.  `ProcessMessages` is generally not a good idea, it can be re-entrant.  If you main thread is not doing anything else, it should be processing messages already!

Answer (score 0):

Although a badly designed script might put you in a do-nothing loop, don't worry about it. Windows is designed to handle this kind of thing, and won't let your program take more than its fair share of the CPU. If it does manage to get 100%, it's only because nothing else wants to run.